# What files startup before you even log on

Tags: windows, boot

For example. If I took an account on a computer and put a file in the startup, then log off and go to a different account will it work? How do I make it run before I even log on to an account.

Comment: what kind of program is it that you want to run?

Answer (score 0):

To have a program start when any user logs on, put a shortcut to the file in
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

(This file is normally hidden)